# Google Families Notifications

Tags: google-family-link

I am trying to turn off email notifications so that I don't get an email each time my son installs something. I have gone to all the steps guided in the support link:

https://support.google.com/families/answer/7184159?hl=en

> Manage notifications When you manage your child's Google Account, you
>   can decide if you want to get notifications through email and the
>   Family Link app.
>
> Note: Certain notifications can't be turned off.
>
> Open the Family Link app Family Link. In the top left, tap Menu Menu
>   and then Notifications settings. Tap the type of notification you
>   would like to change. For each child, turn notifications on or off.
>   You can also change your notification settings from the web:
>
> Visit families.google.com. Click Menu Menu and then Notifications
>   settings. For each child, turn notifications on or off.

The issue is when i go to the "Manage Notifications" there is no place to change these settings. only the below view: (only the "Learn more" is hyperlinked. Same in the actual app itself.)

[image]

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Google needs to sort this out. The information in the Help pages is incorrect. The  notifications management is just a placeholder and hasn't been implemented yet in the either Family Link app or website. Also worth noting that each emails about an app being installed says *"You have received this mandatory email service announcement to update you about important changes to your Google product or account."* This clearly isn't the case either!

Comment: ...As for solving the issue, the best I could do was to set a filter in my Gmail account to delete all such unwanted emails. (Using filter values of **From:** `families-noreply@google.com` and **Subject:** `Installed` if that's any help.)